# where to edit physical_interface_mappings for openstack neutron network

Tags: openstack

I need to edit the physical_interface_mappings. Per the instructions,this setting is in the file below. However, there is no such linuxbirdege folder in /etc/neutron/plugins/. So where should i edit the physical_interface_mappings?

```
/etc/neutron/plugins/linuxbridge/linuxbridge_conf.ini
```

Comment: Are you certain you're using the `linuxbridge` plugin?  What is the `core_plugin` setting in `/etc/neutron/neutron.conf`?  On what distribution are you running OpenStack, and how did you install it?

Answer (score 1):

If neutron-linuxbridge-agent is already running, run to following command to see what config files were used to start the service.

```
ps aux | grep neutron-linuxbridge-agent
```

Else, it might be in /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/.